# instead of html tables use div.. ok but tables are easy so

Tags: html, css

Guys I am a programmer and when I need to add something that looks like a table in the eye and use html tables, I always get smacked by my fellow web designers. How can I construct a common html div structure for divs so I can just have it and always copy paste the html when ever I need something that looks like a table?

So in the case of this table html structure

```
<table>
 <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

what is the similar div structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to use the display `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell`:

CSS:

```
.table
{
   display:table;
}

.table-row
{
   display:table-row;
}

.table-cell
{
   display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">3</div>
      <div class="table-cell">4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SRycV/)

Note that the `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell` display values aren't supported in IE7 or below and IE8 needs a !DOCTYPE.

Also, tables should be used for representing tabular data since it gives the markup more semantic meaning over a bunch of div's with classes. You just shouldn't use tables for layout purposes.

Comment: Beutifull structure and as I test I see I can add more columns and rows without needing to edit the css all the time.. looks perfect amuura

Comment: If you're going to completely copy the entire structure and layout of a table then I think in most cases what you're actually after _is_ a table. Especially if you're still naming your classes "table", "tr", "td" etc (ok not exactly but pretty much). I do agree, however, that `display: table` can be extremely useful in cases when what's being styled is not actually semantically a table. But switching from `table`, `tr` and `td`-elements to `div.table`, `div.tr`, `div.td`-elements seems almost pointless to me.

Comment: display:table-cell; isnt supported by IE7 and IE8 that IE8 need doctype? and what doctype please?

Comment: The doctype is the following: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: great. I think I don't realy care about IE7, They could always use firefox, chrome, safari, opera, or IE8 and Above.. so your solution fits my needs. Thanx again

Comment: @powerbuoy - It's not pointless if your team won't let you use the `table` element to represent tabular data. At least this less semantic div example still has some semantic meaning by naming the classes after the elements that aren't allowed to be used.

Comment: If a team doesn't let you use a table element for tabular data I'd have a serious discussion with that team.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the HTML `table` element for tabular data, then I recommend you smack your fellow web designers back!

HTML tables are not evil, it is acceptable & recommended, to use HTML `table` when displaying tabular data.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm

Comment: Oh absolutely, if it's tabular data you definitely _should_ be using a table.

Comment: Also when they make me create a newsletter, there noway escaping tables, but in the case of websites they are actuall furry about html tables.. But I see your point now

Comment: Tables get a lot of bad reputation because of the use with layout. But its the correct element to use when displaying a **table** of data

Answer (score 4):

I'll use inline styles for simplicity but wouldn't recommend them in a real project:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left"></div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: right"></div>
    <div style="width: 50%; clear: both; float: left"></div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: right"></div>
</div>
```

This is one of many solutions.

The `overflow: hidden` bit is used to "self clear" the container div (without it the div will not wrap around its floated children). The reason the third div clears both is so that it renders on its own row.

Edit: Since the divs are 50% width there's no need to float every other div to the right (you can float them all to the left and it will look identical) but if you want some margin between the divs you can just change the width and every other div will still be aligned to the right (which wouldn't be the case if they were all floated to the left).

Edit: If you are in fact marking up tabular data (as some comments suggest) then by all means stick with the table element. That's what it's there for. You should **absolutely not** just switch from `table`, `tr` and `td` to `div`s with classes of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use some layout like powerbuoy suggested but since you will want to fit the structure to different size in different scenarios you might want to use a grid system in your css to centralize the design layout.

```
.left { float:left; }
.right { float: right }
.onetenth { width: 10%; }
.onetwentieth { width: 5%; }
```

and so on...

I promise you this approach will reduce your styling by a lot resulting in higher performance.

see: https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/    (object-oriented CSS)

Comment: Object Oriented CSS looks neat, I will read it later. Thanx again Mutu

Comment: yeah no problem! you should look up Nicole Sullivan to whom the example belongs to.